# Deploy mule app failed - due to ongoing mule process - Mule EE v3.9.0

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

My mule app contains 93 flows which listens to Directory, FTP, SFTP, http, etc. There is a service which needs polling a NFS directory and process each file. File size is in MB, and we expect to get 1500 to 1800 files in NFS to read/poll. These files are processed in our Mule flow (transformed, splitted, written to another local directory). While this process is getting executed, i tried to deploy a new version of same mule app. I expect, mule to stop the service gracefully, dispose the flow and inner components, and deploy the the new artifact.

The problem is - mule stopping service fails because mule flow is still processing something, and due to that, whole deploy job fails. We cannot accept this situation in Production, and there is no perfect time-slot when mule is silent enough, and we do the deployment.

Is there any process we can skip and on-going processing in mule, and prioritize deploy job (I am normally using Jenkins to deploy new artifacts)?

Will this situation still occur if we deploy/re-deploy mule app through MMC (I haven't tried it though)?

```
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,423 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager:Stopping flow: jdbc_request
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,423 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector:Removing listener on endpointUri: jms://JDBC_REQUEST_INPUT
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,423 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager:Stopping: 'null'. Object is: MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,433 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager:Disposing: 'null'. Object is: MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,433 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager:Stopping service: jdbc_request.stage1
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager:Stopping component: component.939513712
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager:Stopping component: component.1819921531
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager:Stopping component: component.936839367
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager:Stopping component: component.1390541757
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager:Stopping component: component.1072642032
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager:Stopping component: component.277118516
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager:Stopping component: component.237008438
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager:Stopping flow: send_to_ecommerce
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector:Removing listener on endpointUri: jms://OUTBOUND_ADAPTER_INPUT
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,617 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager:Stopping: 'null'. Object is: MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,632 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager:Disposing: 'null'. Object is: MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver
INFO  2020-06-02 10:52:51,632 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager:Stopping service: af19_send_to_ecommerce.stage1
ERROR 2020-06-02 10:52:56,782 [[eis_ap-v4.48.0-SNAPSHOT-4].send_to_ecommerce.stage1.61] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy:tor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:213)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2022)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at org.mule.work.ScheduleWorkExecutor.doExecute(ScheduleWorkExecutor.java:20)
    at org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager.executeWork(MuleWorkManager.java:230)
    at org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager.scheduleWork(MuleWorkManager.java:198)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextAsync(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:162)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:105)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:57)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:71)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultOutboundEndpoint.process(DefaultOutboundEndpoint.java:100)
    at org.mule.endpoint.DynamicOutboundEndpoint.process(DynamicOutboundEndpoint.java:323)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.processParts(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:159)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.process(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:62)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.routing.Foreach.doProcess(Foreach.java:125)
    at org.mule.routing.Foreach.process(Foreach.java:97)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.processEventWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:303)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessors(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:293)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:193)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.processParts(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:159)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.process(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:62)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.processEventWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:303)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessors(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:293)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:193)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.processEventWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:303)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessors(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:293)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:283)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:198)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:48)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:131)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:221)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:214)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:213)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is Jenkins doing to deploy? What method is it using?

Comment: Jenkins job deleted the *anchor*.txt file for the mule app, and copies ZIP file from Nexus to Mule app/ directory for Mule to explode the artifact and generate the app folder

Comment: So you get the error in the logs? are there more lines? is it the mule_ee.log?

Comment: I have added more lines into error trace. There are 2 flows in logs. First one is not processing any message, so its stopping gracefully. Second flow is having on-going process and its actually handling loads of XML files. That's why when deploy job calls, it fails to stop and keeps processing those XML...